# rake aborting -- rspec loaderror

Tags: ruby, macos, rspec, rake

I have: ruby 1.8.7, gem 2.0.3 and rails 2.3.5

Whenever I run rake for a project I need to debug, it gives me the following errors.

> unknown0026bb1748b0:00_hello zed$ rake
>   (in /Users/zedpisec/RUBY/learn_ruby)
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- rspec (LoadError)
>   rake aborted!
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/zed/RUBY/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/zed/RUBY/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/Users/zed/RUBY/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed

My questions are:

1. How am I supposed to interpret this? I would very much would like to know what exactly it is the computer is telling me in order for me to fix this accordingly.

   The exercise requires me to fix an error on the source code but according to the instructions, this is not the error I'm supposed to be getting
2. Are there any specific details I should pay attention to? Here is what it looks like when I ran --trace

> ** Invoke default (first_time)
>   ** Invoke spec (first_time)
>   ** Execute spec
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- rspec (LoadError)
>   rake aborted!
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/zed/RUBY/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/zed/RUBY/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/Users/zed/RUBY/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
>   /Users/zed/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:156:in `run_task'
>   /Users/zed/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:124:in`initialize'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1112:in `verbose'
>   /Users/zed/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:122:in`send'
>   /Users/zed/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:122:in `initialize'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in`call'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in`each'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in`each'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in`invoke_task'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in`each'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in`run'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in`run'
>   /usr/bin/rake:31

My guess is that I did not install something or something needs to be updated. Anyways, any clues or ideas to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated. I apologize if this problem ended up being really simple, I'm new to this thing and am trying to learn my way around it.
I tried looking all over for clues but to no avail, nothing addresses my specific issues. I have tried some solutions offered to people having somewhat a similar problem and it didn't give me any results.

*Help me obi wan kenobi, you're my only hope.*